# node js best elastic search client

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am new to node js and I am trying to work with elastic search.
Tried a few clients

1. [node-es](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-es)
2. https://github.com/phillro/node-elasticsearch-client
3. sage
4. elasticsearch

All of them had issues. My questing is: 
what's the advantage of a node client against just GET'ing the results from the elastic search server? is it for better performance (keeping the connection open)?
Is it for simplicity? (because i got to tell you, they are not so simple to use..)